# Stripping last character in a char* myargs array

Tags: c

I understand this is a rather rudimentary question but I'm still coming learning C char arrays, pointers and the like so any help would be much appreciated.

I currently have a "string" stored at `myargs[1]` where myargs has been defined as `char *myargs[2]`. For this example, let us assume the string is exactly as follows: "Hello how are you " (including the trailing space). I would like to strip the "string" of its trailing space. I understand that char arrays are strings in C and that the char array needs to terminate with a `'\0'` character. However, I am unsure of how to achieve that in such a situation.

EDIT:

To give a bit more context: I am trying to concatenate strings read in from the command line into a single string stored at the address held in myargs[1]. Between each of the strings I add a space and this is done in a while loop until a terminating condition is met. However, as one space is added before the loop terminates, I need to remove that final space. Brief snippets of relevant code are as follows:

```
char *myargs[2];
while (parameterIndex != argc && strcmp(argv[parameterIndex], "+") != 0) {
    printf("%d", parameterIndex);
    printf("\n");
    strcat(myargs[1], argv[parameterIndex]);
    strcat(myargs[1], " ");
    parameterIndex = parameterIndex + 1;
}
```

The concatenated arguments in myargs[1] will be used in the execve library function to execute the command which is now currently stored in myargs[0].

Comment: Replace the space character by '\0'

Comment: @machine_1 may I know how to do that in this case as it is a pointer?

Comment: It depends on the details of your program and on what exactly it means to you to "strip" the trailing space.  If the string can be modified (which is *not* the case if it was initialized with a string literal) then the easiest thing to do would be to overwrite the trailing space with a null terminator, `'\0'`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have an array or a pointer, both can be accessed through the `[]` operation. As in `myargs[1][0]` (which is the first character of the first "argument").

Comment: @pratty, note well that your string is *not* a pointer.  C strings are arrays of `char`.  You have a pointer *to* such an array, but the pointer is not the array, and the array is not the pointer.

Comment: I suggest you add more context as to how you initialize your pointer.

Comment: I have added edits - hopefully this helps! @machine_1

Answer (score 0):

To terminate the string, you need to place the null character right after the last position you want to include.  In your case, what you can do is walk the string backwards until you encounter a non-space character and then place a null character immediately after it.

```
for (int i=strlen(my_string)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (my_string[i] != ' ') {
    my_string[i+1] = '\0';
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that this code will strip all trailing space characters.  If you're guaranteed to only have exactly 1 trailing space character, then it's even simpler:

```
  int length = strlen(my_string);
  my_string[length-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: if my_string is pointer to a constant quoted string, you might not be able to modify it.

Comment: that's correct, i made a whole bunch of assumptions here for simplicity